# Nodejs: How to get Dotenv configuration done first

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm getting an error when initialising Postmark 'Invalid api token'. I'm getting this error because my own environment variables aren't loaded yet.

In index.js I've got a start function. The first thing is configuring dotenv with the correct environment file (development/production/test).

The sendEmail file is loaded before the configuration. I can move the creation of the client inside the sendEmailConfirmationMail function but than I will have the initialize the client for every mail function.

Any other solution?

**index.js**

```
const __dirname = path.resolve();
    
// Load env vars
dotenv.config({ 
   path: path.join(__dirname, `./config/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
});

const start = async () => {
    try {    
        // Connect to database
        await connectDB(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

        // Create app
        const app = express();

        // Body parser
        app.use(express.json())
        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

        // Cookie parser
        app.use(cookieParser());

        // Mount routes
        app.use(`/${process.env.API_VERSION}`, authRoutes);

        // Error handler
        app.use(errorHandler);

        // Not found handler
        app.use(notFoundHandler);

        // Start server
        const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on http://${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}/${process.env.API_VERSION}`)
        });

        // Handle unhandled promise rejections
        process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
            console.log('UNHANDLED REJECTION!  Shutting down...');
            console.log('Unhandled rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);

            // Close server and exit process
            server.close(() => process.exit(1));
        });

        process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
            console.log('UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION!  Shutting down...');
            console.log(err.name, err.message);
        
            // Close server and exit process
            server.close(() => process.exit(1));
        });
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('Server crashed');
        console.log(error);
    }
}

start();
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=production && nodemon --experimental-specifier-resolution=node index.js"
}
```

**utils/sendEmail.js**

```
import postmark from 'postmark';

const client = new postmark.ServerClient(process.env.POSTMARK_API_TOKEN);

export const sendEmailConfirmationMail = async (email, first_name, language, confirmation_token) => {    
    return client.sendEmailWithTemplate({
        To: email,
        From: process.env.MAIL_FROM,
        TemplateId: language === 'fr' ? 19699565 : 19699566,
        TemplateModel: {
            "first_name": first_name,
            "url": `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/confirm-email?confirmation_token=${confirmation_token}&email=${email}&lang=${language}`
        }
    });
}
```